# Can't create new user via DocuSign Quickstart App (Unauthorized error)

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I have a problem with creating another user by Admin API. I created an organization and authorized Quickstart App using recommended scopes as stated in this article https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/admin101/application-auth/

But I was faced with an Unauthorized Error in Quickstart App
[image: Unauthorized Error]

Thanks.

Comment: did you update or modify scopes in any way?  If using the Quickstart you shouldn't need to modify anything because it was configured when you downloaded it

Comment: No, I did not modify anything in this application.
I use it as a code example.

Comment: as @IvanD mentioned, if you don't have a registered domain user attempting to register, the quickstart will give you an error as the code behind the scenes is attempting to use an option -auto_activate as true. That will require you to have a domain registered to the account and that  the email used to register matches that same domain. Ie a domain of frankenmint.com would allow a user@frankenmint.com to  register, but trying to register frankenmint@gmail.com would trigger an error, as configured

Answer (score 1):

Have you claimed your domain? Can you check if your new user email domain is the same as your claimed org domain?